# How to create a single foreign key that points to a multiple-column primary key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have created with MySQL 5.5 a table1 with a multiple-column primary key, created from two FLOAT columns. I want to create a table2 with a single foreign key that points to the primary key of table1.

Is it possible? How can I do it, and it's possible / it's fast to do using phpmyadmin GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a single foreign key that references two columns. But it's not possible for a foreign key that consists of *one* column to reference *two* columns. Let's say that all these columns were integers. What value would you store in a *single* integer column in table_2 that would match *two* integer columns in table_1?

```
alter table table_2
add constraint your_constraint_name
foreign key (column_1, column_2) references table_1 (column_1, column_2);
```

This assumes that the primary key columns in table_1 are named "column_1" and "column_2", and that in table_2, the corresponding columns have the same names.

You need to use the InnoDB engine for MySQL to enforce foreign keys.

Comment: So it's not possible to link one single column of table_2 to the multiple-column primary key of table_1? I'm asking this because I'm figuring multiple-column primary as an index with its own values, generated from values of the columns of the primary key, but I suppose this is not correct.

Comment: No, it's not possible for one column to reference two columns. Let's say that all these columns were integers. What value would you store in a *single* integer column in table_2 that would match *two* integer columns in table_1?